# Adding 1000 names to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm having this issue where I have 1000 users which I need assign to them their unique 'ID', 'username/renum' and 'password' (md5 hash). I need to create table with VALUES for id, category, name, username, regnum(same as ID) and password.

So i have created php file that generates the unique 'ID', 'username' and 'password' for all 1000 users using this:

```
<?php
//creates a unique id  username(renum)  and password using rand and md5

//creates a longer unique id with the 'about' prefix
$a= 0;
echo " id &nbsp &nbsp regnum &nbsp &nbsp password <br>";
while($a<1000) {
$a=$a+1;
srand($a);
$b = rand();
$c = strval($b);
$d = md5($c);
echo $a, "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp",$b,"&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp", $d, "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}
```

and I also have have full list of users including VALUES : name, category and regnum. **THIS IS STORED IN WORD and EXCEL file (table format)**

Now as I am still new to mySql and php I cannot figure out how I can merge values I generated (username, id, password) with (name, regnum*same as id and category) these two in a php style which then i can import to the table in phpmyadmin.

OR even better is there way to create form where I coudl enter name of the user and as I submit the name, create php code that will automatically assign the values to the name which are randomally generated anyway???

I could style page where I could add values to the table or do it through phpmyadmin but as this is 1000 users, it would take a while to do each one individually therefore I was wondering if there is any way of doing it quicker way.

So this is just how I wrote little coding for mysql to create database and table with few values:
[CODE EXAMPLE](http://codepad.org/DVZIuLOF)

and I used it to import the values to table through phpmyadmin, and now wanting to add rest of the users, I cannot find a way to do so as adding them individually would be painful.

Thats the point where I need to add rest of the values but its so time consuming therefore I wonder if theres any other way to do this as I cannot find anything helpful.

Much appreciate your ideas and help to achieve my goal.

Comment: First, I would not suggest using an `MD5` hash for passwords. It is no longer considered secure because it is too fast to execute. Second, do not create the unique identifier yourself. Your SQL server will take care of that for you, because you added the `AUTO_INCREMENT` flag when creating the table. Third, look into `PDO` for accessing (read/write) the database. Lastly. I think PHPMyAdmin can actually read various formats and insert this data for you.